# Cannot connect to the configuration database - SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sql-server-2008

From last few days I am getting this error every morning.

When I check SQL service in service manager, its status is "Started", but when i restart it, the problem gets resolved.

This is happening every day. What can be reason?

Below is a screenshot of our disk space for Database server:
[image]

Currently All new data files goes in H drive and log files goes in G drive.

RAM for database server is 120 GB. It has around 500 Content DBs.

Comment: Could be lots of things. Like is the memory to low on your db-server? Does it have enough disk space? Can you see SQL do dumps?

Comment: check service account for sqlservice it expire or not and it can be for many reasons, tell what in event viewer

Comment: Hi adil, service account might be not an issue as same account is used on another server and there it is working properly.

Comment: Event Viewer Shows only two error in that time span:  Event ID 1, Source: SQLVDI  and Event ID: 18056, Source: MSSQLSERVER

Comment: Hi Robert: I have updated my Question with screenshot. SQL Don't give error once i restart.

Comment: We have added one more core in CPU, now it seems to be working. Today we didn't got the error. We will keep under observations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after adding one more core to CPU. Seems that performance was the issue.